# Add string to tokens of a string if token is within characters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string,

```
test = "if 'col.A' not null and if 'col.B' not 'null'
```

I want to add `str(row[...]` for the tokens which are encapsulated within `''` and contains a `.` in the token. How can I achieve this in python, I'm not a regex pro. Prior to this I was manually replacing, but since the number elements within `''` are to increase, I want to automate it. I want the end result to be like,

```
test = "if str(row['col.A']) not null and if str(row['col.B']) not 'null'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import re

test = "if 'col.A' not null and if 'col_B' not null"

out = re.sub(r"'([^']*\.[^']*)'", r"str(row['\1'])", test)
print(out)

# Output:
if str(row['col.A']) not null and if 'col_B' not null
```

Comment: I have updated the question, I want to add `str(row[...]` for the tokens which are encapsulated within `''` and contains a `.`